# Decompressing Gzip Python

Tags: python

I am facing challenges to decompress some data in Python. I am compressing in a `inverted_index.txt` file the values of a large dictionary called '`idf`'. I am keeping track of the offset and the size for each value stored in the `inverted_index.txt` on an `catalog.txt`. The `catalog.txt` is a dictionary that is using the same `key` of the `idf` as a key and it's value if a `tuple` (`offset in bytes, size in bytes`).

**my idf (dic of dics):**

```
instead[{'AP891220-0001': [1]}, {'AP891220-0034': [512]}, {'AP891220-0073': [311]}, {'AP891220-0078': [231]}, {'AP891220-0079': [137]}]
of[{'AP891220-0001': [2, 53, 110, 550, 600, 612, 619, 629, 639, 678, 685]}, {'AP891220-0002': [10 222, 242, 292, 340, 357]}, {'AP891220-0003': [4, 381, 520, 539, 542, 663, 850, 869, 873, 909, 923, 931, 988, 994, 1014, 1033, 1044, 1061, 1106, 1118, 1153]}, states[{'AP891220-0001': [7]}, {'AP891220-0007': [117]}...
```

**catalog.txt:**

```
{"instead": [0, 80], "of": [80, 2960], "collapsing": [3040, 44], "when": [3084, 435], "the": [3519, 5752], "united": [9271, 472], "states": [9743, 521], "threw": [10264, 72], "its": [10336, 361], "military": [10697, 412], "might": [11109, 139],..
```

inverted_index.txt (bytes):

```
��{{^���Vw��4422�5000T�R�6���Q@76��aȘ�d�...
```

**This is how I am compressing:**

```
with open(current_inverted_index, "wb") as my_file:
    for key in idf:
        data = str(idf[key])
        current_offset = my_file.tell()
        compressed_index = gzip.compress(data.encode('ISO-8859-1'))
        current_size = my_file.write(compressed_index)
        current_catalog[key] = (current_offset, current_size)
```

However, I was not able to decompress correctly, the size is not correct:

```
with gzip.open(path, "rb") as f:
    f.seek(0) 
    data = f.read(80)
    decoded = data.decode('ISO-8859-1')
    print(decoded)
    with open("samples/instead.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(decoded)
```

result: `[{'AP891220-0001': [1]}, {'AP891220-0034': [512]}, {'AP891220-0073': [311]}, {'A`

As you can see, the result is not correct, seems the read() in decompress is not reading bytes but it's reading just char by char. I don't know how to be able to solve this...

Comment: When you `read()` from a `gzip.open()`, the argument is the amount of decompressed content to *write*, not the number of bytes to *read*. If you want to control the number of bytes read, copy the content into a buffer (like a `StringIO` object) and decompress from there.

Comment: Thanks, when you are saying the 'content' what do you mean by that?

Comment: Whatever the stream *decompresses to*. You can't do a seek in a gzip archive unless you have a bunch of small, separately-compressed streams. I'm *assuming* that's what you're actually doing, because that's the only context in which the question makes sense. Of course, your index needs to point to the places in the original, *uncompressed* file where those compressed streams start.

Comment: (Also, gzip is probably a bad choice for this use case in general; `zstd` supports sharing a single compression table across lots of different compressed files/objects/streams/whatever-you-want-to-call-them, which makes the overhead far lower).

Comment: ...once you're decompressing a single stream, the only way to move forward is to read the content in front of you and run the algorithm. If that means decompressing-and-discarding content between the front and when you reach what you want to get to, that's what needs to happen. Which is why I was saying that you really want a separate stream starting *after* you seek to your lookup point.